# jQuery function enable a div

Tags: jquery, html

I'm this code embed my js file for win key close. This codes:

```
jQuery(document).keydown(function(e){
    alert(e.keyCode); // replace "37" below with the windows key code
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
       alert( "windows key pressed" );
       return false;
    }
});
```

Working good. But i want only work 1 div. How can i do this?

Comment: you mean the keydown event on one div? how do you type inside a div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the selector instead of document

`jQuery('selector')` instead of `jQuery(document)`

where selector can be anything like id, class e.t.c

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/LfRCv/) which uses selector as id

[Another Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/xCpn9/1/) will work for only one input inside a div.

[Div Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/HUx4M/1/) will work only for first div

[Disabled for Div](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/N8LMk/1/) will work only for span not for div

[Disabled for input in div](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/4wVDF/1/) will work for all input if they are not inside a div

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
jQuery(document).keydown(function(e) {
```

To

```
jQuery("#myElement").keydown(function(e) {
```

Where `#myElement` is the `id` of your `div`.

Comment: Thank you. Well, how to disable for a div?

Answer (score 2):

Use your div selector instead of `document` selector.

```
jQuery("#yourdivid").keydown(function(e){
    alert(e.keyCode); // replace "37" below with the windows key code
    if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
       alert( "windows key pressed inside div" );
       return false;
    }
});
```

To disable a div, you can simple use `$("#yourdivid").prop('disabled', true);`

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the div you want it to work on:

```
jQuery("#theIdOfTheDiv").keydown(function(e){ 
    alert(e.keyCode); // replace "37" below with the windows key code 
    if (e.keyCode == 37) {  
       alert( "windows key pressed" ); 
       return false; 
    } 
});
```

Change 'theIdOfTheDiv' with the name of your div.

Answer (score 1):

give an ID to your div. for examle

```
<div id="testdiv" tabindex="0"></div>
```

Now write code to bind keydown event to it, on document ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#testdiv").keydown(function(e) {

                if (e.keyCode == 37) { 
                alert( "windows key pressed" );
                return false;
                }
            });
        });
```

but remember to assign a tabindex to DIV, it can any **number**.